# Non-vulgar word for 'Clusterf**k'?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, offensive-language, euphemisms

Is there a non-vulgar word for 'clusterfuck'? I searched here, but there are no related questions (that I could find). There are suggestions like 'mess' or 'disaster', but that is not the original meaning of 'clusterfuck' as far as I am concerned. I think it means more like a collection of many, multiple very different things but the word 'collection' also seems not to cover the meaning of 'clusterfuck'. Any suggestions?

---

Edit from comments:

What I mean is something like a mix of various things. Like e.g. *my head is full of stuff* --> *my head is a clusterfuck of thoughts*. Meaning there is a lot going on and it is also topicless or it has many topics. Neither mess nor disaster nor mix are in my opinion strong enough words to cover it. I am not searching for a negative word, but a neutral one (maybe even positive, if I don't find anything else).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner's use of the term 'clusterfuck' is at odds with its definition of 'disastrously mishandled situation or undertaking', limiting the future usefulness of answers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55799/discussion-on-question-by-emelie-non-vulgar-word-for-clusterfk).

Answer (score 7):

Consider ***[Omnishambles](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnishambles)***

> NOUN British  informal
>   A situation that has been comprehensively
> mismanaged, characterized by a string of blunders and miscalculations.
> *‘anyone with five minutes to spare, a Maths GCSE, and a calculator
> could have averted the entire omnishambles by checking the civil
> servants' sums’*
>
> Origin
> Early 21st century: from omni- + shambles, first used in the British satirical television series The Thick of It.

In further support of this; I just asked a friend what 'omnishambles' meant, he said, 'clusterf*ck' (though his pronunciation of '*' is questionable)

Answer (score 5):

A **train wreck** is an utter disaster or mess; a disastrous calamity or source of trouble. ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/train%20wreck))

It is a catastrophe, typically so unmanageable that it can't be hidden and it attracts outsiders to observe and comment.

It happens, like a perfect storm, where everything collapses all at once into one huge mess.

A person can be described as a *train wreck*, which, in the right context, can mean that they are seriously messed up in some respect, not normal, out of control.

> His thoughts were so convoluted and confused that his mind had become a train wreck.